# What is wrong with my Perl script?

Tags: html, perl, email

Probably everything in my opinion!

I basically don't know what I'm doing. I've never written a .cgi file before, but I did write the script basing myself on several tutorials...
One of them is this one...
http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/cgi/processingforms.html

I want a Perl script that will process an html form, collect the user's data and send to email with a return Thank you.html file to user when they hit SUBMIT.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);

if ($ENV{'REQUEST_METHOD'} eq 'POST') {

read(STDIN, $buffer, $ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'});

@pairs = split(/&/, $buffer);

foreach $pair (@pairs) {
    ($name, $value) = split(/=/, $pair);
    $value =~ tr/+/ /;
    $value =~ s/%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])/pack("C", hex($1))/eg;
    $FORM{$name} = $value;

}

if( $FORM{magazine} ){
    $magazine_flag ="ON";
}else{
    $magazine_flag ="OFF";
}

if( $FORM{internet} ){
    $internet_flag ="ON";
}else{
    $internet_flag ="OFF";
}

if( $FORM{distributor} ){
    $distributor_flag ="ON";
}else{
    $distributor_flag ="OFF";
}

if( $FORM{yes1} ){
    $yes1_flag ="ON";
}else{
    $yes1_flag ="OFF";
}

if( $FORM{no1} ){
    $no1_flag ="ON";
}else{
    $no1_flag ="OFF";
}

if( $FORM{twofifty} ){
    $twofifty_flag ="ON";
}else{
    $twofifty_flag ="OFF";
}

if( $FORM{fivehundred} ){
    $fivehundred_flag ="ON";
}else{
    $fivehundred_flag ="OFF";
}

if( $FORM{thousand} ){
    $thousand_flag ="ON";
}else{
    $thousand_flag ="OFF";

}

if( $FORM{twofivehundred} ){
    $twofivehundred_flag ="ON";
}else{
    $twofivehundred_flag ="OFF";
}

if( $FORM{fivethousand} ){
    $fivethousand_flag ="ON";
}else{
    $fivethousand_flag ="OFF";

}

if( $FORM{tenthousand} ){
    $tenthousand_flag ="ON";
}else{
    $tenthousand_flag ="OFF";
}

if( $FORM{fifteenthousand} ){
    $fifteenthousand_flag ="ON";
}else{
    $fifteenthousand_flag ="OFF";
}

if( $FORM{yes2} ){
    $yes2_flag ="ON";
}else{
    $yes2_flag ="OFF";
}

if( $FORM{no2} ){
    $no2_flag ="ON";
}else{
    $no2_flag ="OFF";
}

if( $FORM{yes3} ){
    $yes3_flag ="ON";
}else{
    $yes3_flag ="OFF";
}

if( $FORM{no3} ){
    $no3_flag ="ON";
}else{
    $no3_flag ="OFF";
}


$Magazine-name = $FORM{magazine-name};
$Name = $FORM{name};
$Title = $FORM{title};
$Job = $FORM{job};
$Company = $FORM{company};
$Address = $FORM{address};
$City = $FORM{city};
$State = $FORM{state};
$Zip = $FORM{zip};
$Telephone = $FORM{telephone};
$E-mail = $FORM{e-mail};




open (MESSAGE,"| /usr/sbin/sendmail -t");

print MESSAGE "To: aalmeida\@aemc.com\n"; 
print MESSAGE "From: " . $Name . ", reader\n";
print MESSAGE "Reply-to: " . $E-mail . "(" . $Name . ")\n";

print MESSAGE "Subject: NECA 2013 Registration to win from $Name \n\n";

print MESSAGE "$Name wrote:\n\n";
print MESSAGE "Where do you look most often for test instrumentation?:\n\n"; 
print MESSAGE "$magazine_flag\n\n";
print MESSAGE "$magazine-name\n\n";
print MESSAGE "$internet_flag\n\n";
print MESSAGE "$distributor_flag\n\n";
print MESSAGE "$representative_flag\n\n";
print MESSAGE "I have a need for insulation testing:\n\n";
print MESSAGE "$yes1_flag\n\n";
print MESSAGE "$no1_flag\n\n";
print MESSAGE "What test voltage is important?:\n\n";
print MESSAGE "$twofifty_flag\n\n";
print MESSAGE "$fivehundred_flag\n\n";
print MESSAGE "$thousand_flag\n\n";
print MESSAGE "$twofivehundred_flag\n\n";
print MESSAGE "$fivethousand_flag\n\n";
print MESSAGE "$tenthousand_flag\n\n";
print MESSAGE "$fifteenthousand_flag\n\n";
print MESSAGE "Is the ability to store test results from the 
    instrument important?:\n\n";
print MESSAGE "$yes2_flag\n\n";
print MESSAGE "$no2_flag\n\n";
print MESSAGE "Do you plan to purchase within the next 6 months?:\n\n";
print MESSAGE "$yes3_flag\n\n";
print MESSAGE "$no3_flag\n\n";
print MESSAGE "Name: $FORM{name}\n\n";
print MESSAGE "Title: $FORM{title}\n\n";
print MESSAGE "Job Function: $FORM{job}\n\n";
print MESSAGE "Company: $FORM{company}\n\n";
print MESSAGE "Address: $FORM{address}\n\n";
print MESSAGE "City: $FORM{city}\n\n";
print MESSAGE "State: $FORM{state}\n\n";
print MESSAGE "Zip: $FORM{zip}\n\n";
print MESSAGE "Telephone: $FORM{telephone}\n\n";
print MESSAGE "E-mail: $FORM{e-mail}\n\n";



close (MESSAGE);


exit(0);
```

When I hit submit from the browser, I get this error:

Software error:

> Can't modify subtraction (-) in scalar assignment at \boswinfs05\home\users\web\b465\whl.caadmin\www\HTML-email\SP_ToolKitPROMO_NECA2013\functions\formmailer.cgi line 117, near "};"
>   Missing right curly or square bracket at \boswinfs05\home\users\web\b465\whl.caadmin\www\HTML-email\SP_ToolKitPROMO_NECA2013\functions\formmailer.cgi line 180, at end of line
>   syntax error at \boswinfs05\home\users\web\b465\whl.caadmin\www\HTML-email\SP_ToolKitPROMO_NECA2013\functions\formmailer.cgi line 180, at EOF
>   Execution of \boswinfs05\home\users\web\b465\whl.caadmin\www\HTML-email\SP_ToolKitPROMO_NECA2013\functions\formmailer.cgi aborted due to compilation errors.

For help, please send mail to this site's webmaster, giving this error message and the time and date of the error.

How can I make the script work?

Any insight would be much appreciated or links to more in depth tutorials would also be great.

Thanks!

Comment: You're using the CGI module, but parsing the form submission data yourself? Why?

Comment: I am currently testing the form from browser and sending the data to myself to see how goes...

Comment: Instead of parsing the content as you are use the CGI modules build in methods to do so. Start with `my $q = CGI->new; $q->param("yourLabel");` or you can even get params as a hash and parse that `my %params = $q->Vars;`

Comment: What does CGI modules mean? Are we still talking Perl here?

Comment: @AAL - you are using the CGI::Carp module. CGI is another module. use it. Though there alternatives these days ... Dancer,Mojo,etc., but go ahead and start with CGI. Also, [use strict and warnings](http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=111088)

Comment: The Perl community has build up a mass of libraries that make your coding life easier. Some are packaged with Perl and others you have to install yourself. You have CGI::Carp, so you should also already have CGI. When you add statement `use CGI;` you are loading the library CGI. Libraries, or modules as they are called in perl, add functionality to the base language.

Comment: Check out the site perldoc.perl.org for more tutorials and examples in perl. For instance the cgi module is discussed here: http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html

Comment: @runrig is CGI module easier to parse content than Carp? If there is a benefit in using one rather than the other, I'll use it.

Comment: All CGI::Carp does is allow writing to the error log. It does nothing to parse the content. http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI/Carp.html.

Comment: That tutorial you linked to is horrible...read the CGI library docs. You should not have to parse form parameters.

Comment: @scrappedcola Ok thanks for the link and the info. Very helpful

Comment: CGI::Carp fatalsToBrowser displays errors to the browser...convenient for debugging, but do not use in production. 'Users' should not know about your internal workings.

Answer (score 6):

You are using hyphens in those identifiers.

```
$Magazine-name = $FORM{magazine-name};
$E-mail = $FORM{e-mail};
```

Change those to underscores.

Enable syntax highlighting in your editor. That will help you catch such errors quickly even before compiling.

Comment: @AAL, you can use dashes, they just have to be quoted (e.g. `$FORM{'magazine-name'}`.

Comment: What syntax editor should I be using? Instead of Notepad that is??

Comment: Notepad doesnt have syntax highlighting. Try Gvim or Notepad++

Comment: @Jean thanks! Yes, this was making things a bit more difficult

Answer (score 2):

`$E-mail` and `$Magazine-name` are not valid variable names. Only letters, numbers, and the underscore characters can be used in a variable name(*). Try `$E_mail` or `$Email`.

(*) - without a little symbol table wizardry or other hacks that leave an impression of Perl as a write-only language

Answer (score 0):

Tips:

- Always use `use strict; use warnings;`!
- Use the following instead of handling the CGI yourself:

  ```
  use CGI qw( );

  my $cgi  = CGI->new();
  my $form = $cgi->Vars();

  # Use $form->{...} instead of $FORM{...}
  ```
- ```
  if( $form->{magazine} ){
      $magazine_flag ="ON";
  }else{
      $magazine_flag ="OFF";
  }

  if( $form->{internet} ){
  ...
  ```

  could be written as

  ```
  $form->{$_} = $form->{$_} ? "ON" : "OFF"
     for qw(
        magazine
        internet
        ...
     );
  ```